# Symbolic Link to a folder not shared in a shared folder

Tags: windows

I have this backup folder for each of my childer, myself and my wife. Each of them is shared from my PC as I don't have a server yet, now I found a way to backup our phones to each of our backup folders, sadly after my wife phone broke.

Now we bought a temp cheap backup phone for her and everyone else to use while we try and get the real phone fixed or at least file restored.
I backup the content of that in a separate place to make it easier if we need to use that or another again.

Here is where my problem came I don't want to share the backup of the temp phone folders so I created a symbolic link to the specific folder for my Wife, children and me in our shared folders to the non shared folder of the temp phone.

First I got a error message that turned out was easy fixed, I used fsutil to activate remote to local and remote to remote which got rid of the original error but I had to do it on my PC and each of the PC's but now instead of working it gives this error: "The device is not ready" plus it shows the physical link on my pc drive and all above it.

I have tried adding the folders to shared no go, I just don't want to share the temp folder and have them to go 2 places, as everything is meant to be under each of their own backup folder that was shared, so is there a way to fix this symbolic link issue I can keep the temp backup of the shared network and just give access to their specific temp phone backup via symbolic link?

I hope it makes sense people if not please let me know I am trying my best to describe it.

Shared folders:

f:\Name Backup

non shared folder but symbolic link

f:\Backup Phone\Name

In each of the Name Backup have I created a symbolic link called Temp Phone or Backup Phone I can't remember not sitting at my pc, anyway the symbolic link of this link straight to the folder f:\Backup Phone\Name

Under which the backup of the temp phone is stored.

Replace "Name" with the name of my children, me and wife just easier to do it that way.

Comment: Hello. Your question is better suited for a different community. I will flag your question to be moved to it, since it's both more likely you'll get help and offtopic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay where will it be moved to? Sorry very new on here and saw something about symbolic link and thought I did it right @JettoMartínez

Comment: Huh, it's taking kind of long. Since you're asking about general computing, it's better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com). StackOverflow is related to programming (Hence is not the best community for your question). If your question isn't moved automatically, I recommend you post it there by yourself.

Comment: @JettoMartínez Ok thank you so much for the help, I will look at that site and post if this is not moved automatically, Appreciate it very much.